# Reset Java BufferedReader after parsing

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I know this is done with mark() and reset().  However I'm very new to reading in files and my code doesn't work and I know my mistake is probably pretty obvious and stupid I just can't figure it out.  I've tried moving things around it just hasn't worked out.  The goal of my code is to pop up a joption pane the first time a null line is found(which i haven't gotten to yet), and then return to the top of the file.  This is probably a dumb question but if someone can help me out I'd really appreciate it.  By the way the issue is getting the IOException thrown after the last line is read( It executes this method each time a jbutton is clicked ).

```
public static void fileReader( String inputFile , JTextField array[] )
{
    /** Local Constants **/

    final String NOT_READABLE = "File not readable!!";
    final String IO_ERROR     = "Input/Output Error!!";

    /** Local Variables **/

    String line;

    if ( inStream == null )
    {
        fileOpen( inputFile );
    }

    if ( isReadableFile( inputFile ) )
    {
       try
       { 

         line = inStream.readLine();
         inStream.mark( 64 );

         if ( line != null )
         {
            int j = 0;

            for ( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ )
            {
                if ( Character.isDigit( line.charAt( i ) ) )
                {
                    if ( j < array.length )
                       array[ j ].setText( line.charAt( i ) +
                                           MagicSquareGUI.BLANK );

                    j++;
                }
            }
         }

         else
         {
            inStream.close();
            inStream.reset();
         }
     }

     catch ( IOException e )
     {
        System.out.println( IO_ERROR );
     }

     catch ( Exception e )
     {
        System.out.println( ERROR );
     }
  }

  else
     System.out.println( NOT_READABLE );

}
```

Comment: "my code doesn't work", "it just hasn't worked out", etc., are not adequate problem descriptions. You need to describe the behaviour you are seeing and what you are expecting. You say your goal is to see a popup when you get `null` from `readLine()`, so why isn't there any code to handle that case? Not a real question.

Comment: Well it doesn't reset(I had mentioned I hadn't cared about the joptionpane yet).  It throws the IOException.  I apologize for not including in the original post I just forgot after I had to realign all the code for 5 minutes since you can't copy and past in here without messing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  I moved the mark() into the fileOpen() method called within the method above.  It now marks properly and resets the way it's supposed to.

Comment: That is what I had suggested. Read **Answer Updated #1** and 1 of the sub-sequents comment.

Comment: That's after I made the same comment earlier... You basically restated it the same way I said it.

Comment: It didn't work in the exact location you said I had already tried that.  You also said I can't have it under that if ( inStream == null ), which is where it is and it's working.

Comment: I even said right before that first comment I tried putting in that other place so it read RIGHT after the file was opened.  THEN you basically repeated that statement on your next comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error `IOException` after you try resetting the `stream`.

**Possibilities:**

**1)** The `reset` you are calling on the `type of stream class` may not be supported. `Reset` is not supported by all types of streams.

**2)** You have already read the bytes. In this case, `Reset` will fail. `Reset` is supported only if the bytes are not already read more than the ***mark*** limit. Check your `line` variable and its length if you are already reading the bytes.

**Answer Updated:**

**1)** You need to `mark` before you start reading. It should be like this:

```
     inStream.mark( 64 );
     line = inStream.readLine();
```

**2)** Don't close the *stream* unless you are finished with it. Closing the `stream` and then use `Reset` is wrong.

This line `inStream.close()` needs to be removed from current `else` and put it *in the end* of the function, probably after *last* `else`.

**3)** One more thing I want to point out to you is that you are only reading *1st line* in the text file. Your stream reader is not in the loop.

**I tested** your function successfully with the mentioned changes.

Comment: Ah.  Yeah all I'm using is BufferedReader.  I'm guessing that's the problem then?

Comment: To elaborate on the BufferedReader I instantiate it as inStream = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( inputFile ) );

Comment: `BufferedReader` supports `reset`. So, that is fine. Check 2nd possibility I have suggested.

Comment: I dont think the second could be the case because the way I'm testing the file right now theres

Comment: only two lines.  If I had mark( 1000 ) that wouldn't go over with 2 lines of text file right?

Comment: Here's the problem.  Yes it does only read one line at a time.  I didn't mention it is supposed to do that.  Because of that, marking at that spot you mentioned won't/doesn't work because as my jbutton gets hit and method gets called again it just marks until the last line of the file and more or less continuously resets at the last line of the file.  That's where the major problem is.  I should also mention I got rid of the last else it never gets reached anyways under normal conditions anyways so I don't think it'll be that helpful.

Comment: So basically I just need to mark it ONLY the first time it's called.  I tried putting it under the if ( inStream == null ) so it marks RIGHT when it's opened but that doesn't seem to work either.  I know that way had to be close to what I actually need but not quite right.

Comment: Whatever your functional requirement may be, moral of the story is you will have to `mark` before you start reading your stream. And don't put under `inStream == null`. This is wrong. You don't set `mark` on `NULL` stream.

Comment: The fileOpen() call opens it and instantiates it before that mark would be called inside that if structure.  And such is my dilemma.  If i mark any farther along it just redoes it every time the method is called.  Can you think of any other way to do it?

Comment: what does this mean ? >> *"it just redoes it every time the method is called"*. What is the purpose of this ?

Comment: It resets to the last line and runs the last line over and over.  There is literally nowhere else to go with the mark statement that I haven't tried. I'm officially lost.

Comment: I know the reset is working though because I don't get an IO error that i'd get without the reset statement

Answer (score 0):

You can't reset a stream or Reader after you close it. Leave it open.

Comment: Where would I go with that close statement then?

Comment: *After* you've finished with it. Closing it and then resetting it and then presumably trying to re-read from it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So in this particular case would I ever want it closed?  In this case we're really not "done" with it until the user is done using the program period.

Comment: You should close it when `readLine()` returns `null,` which you should be testing for.

Comment: then when would I reset it? I wouldn't want it reset before readLine is null either would I?